# Gitlab migration - clone Issues & Merge Requests

Tags: git, github

I'm doing gitlab migration.

1) I cloned first repo with Export/Import option and everything seems fine.

2) Then I wasn't able to use Import option on the second one, so I decided to use clone/push combination.

Unfortunately, all Issues and Merge Requests gone.

**It is any way to clone only those?** I did some changes to new repo and I don't want to clone whole again.

-- version: GitLab Community Edition 9.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it's OK to discard all issues and merge requests of second one, you can delete second one and then import, after import, git push -f to change code back